# Decoding in asp.net 4.0 - Special Characters

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

decoding of a special characters in asp.net as per the W3C standards. ASCII - URL encoding chart. Some of the special characters are not being converted instead converting to "?", check the below issue, actual result for %92 ASCII is "`", I'm trying to achieve this to decode to a urlencoding equal character.

```
strurl="Workers%92+Accommodation";
string strdecode=Server.UrlDecode(strurl);
```

Ex: ASCII code %92 (as per W3C standarards url encoding is for ' - which is not there in key board refer http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/ref_urlencode.asp).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to decode with appropriate encoding codepage. Quoting from [http://www.ascii-code.com](http://www.ascii-code.com/):

> There are several different variations of the 8-bit ASCII table. The table below is according to ISO 8859-1, also called ISO Latin-1....

According to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_code_page, codepage for ISO Latin-1 is `1252`. To decode your string, simply do the following:

```
strurl = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252).
             GetString(HttpUtility.UrlDecodeToBytes("%92"));
```

Comment: It is not giving the expected result as per the HTML URL Encoding Reference (http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/ref_urlencode.asp)

Comment: Thanks, I come to know First Need to identify the page encoding and then while decoding consider the same charset..NET defaults strings are always in Unicode encoding, URL decode happens default charset UTF 32... Correct me If I am wrong.. Any how that gave me the desired result.

Comment: @Janardhan I'm sorry I couldn't understand your issue. Could you please elaborate a bit?

Comment: Actually I have been asked this issue because one of my ASP.NET page receiving http post(posted form keys) values ( say WORKER%92S),When I tried applying this at the time of reading the form.key values, I couldn't succeed. Not sure the same hardcoded string converts as expected. Its in production I can't debug

Answer (score 4):

try to encode/decode with this:

```
public static string EncodeString(string decodedString)
{
    return Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(decodedString));
}

public static string DecodeString(string encodedString)
{
    return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(encodedString));
}
```

edit add:
When you are going to transmit a value via a URL the method to use is the: HttpServerUtility.UrlTokenEncode() method

reference:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.urltokenencode.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Actually encoding is been done by other application not in my control, however the value posted to my page is "Workers%92+Accommodation", which needs to be converted to the plain text, which is not happening with URLdecode. With the above function decodestring  returns "?".

Comment: When you are going to transmit a value via a URL the method to use is the: HttpServerUtility.UrlTokenEncode() method

Comment: Correct,However I am not worried in posting data, worried about posted data which is been received in the form.

Comment: Getting the error::The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or a non-white space character among the padding characters.